# Is Spec of a ring monoidal or anti-monoidal?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, tensor-products, products

Let $A$ and $B$ be rings. A very senior mathematician impressed on me the importance of writing
$$
\operatorname{Spec}{A \otimes B} = \operatorname{Spec}{B} \times \operatorname{Spec}{A}
$$
One can find this, for example, in 4.0.5 of [Brown - Integral points on curves, the unit equation, and motivic periods](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00555).

On the other hand, most mathematicians write
$$
\operatorname{Spec}{A \otimes B} = \operatorname{Spec}{A} \times \operatorname{Spec}{B},
$$
as in 6.3.5 of Vakil's notes [Foundations of algebraic geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf), the proof of Theorem II.3.3 in Hartshorne, or 3.2.2, p. 104, of [EGA I](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1960__4__5_0).

Which one is correct? More specifically, what are the benefits and downsides of each? Does something go wrong if one writes things in the latter manner?

Comment: Given that both categories (of rings and schemes) are symmetric monoidal, I don't think there is going to be significant benefit from writing either.

Comment: @Wojowu : it might (a priori) be that the categories are symmetric monoidal but the functor is only monoidal. But here it's not the case : the monoidality of the functor comes from its preserving  finite products (or coproducts, depending on which category we decide to op), so there is no such subtlety here

Comment: Both are canonical isomorphisms yes, but I think the question is about the fact that one can freely assume that one of these is an equality instead of an isomorphism (and obviously not both). But that is only going to affect how many canonical isomorphisms we have to keep track of, so not a very significant change.

Comment: Your link to Vakil's notes is to an old version.  The current version is [Foundations of algebraic geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGaug2922publici.pdf), and a list of all the versions is at [216 blog](https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog).

Answer (score 1):

Just because $Spec$ is contravariant on 1-morphisms doesn't mean it has to be contravariant on 0-morphisms.

As indicated in the comments, $Spec$ is naturally monoidal. You can make it anti-monoidal if you like. Whether this is a good idea or not may depend on your conventions regarding how left / right actions correspond to "composition order".

More precisely,

- Let $BRing$ be the 2-category with one object whose 1-morphisms are given by commutative rings and 2-morphisms are homomorphisms between such. Horizontal composition is given by tensor product, and vertical composition is given by usual composition of homomorphisms.
- Let $BScheme$ be the 2-category with one object, with 1-morphisms given by schemes and 2-morphisms given by morphisms of schemes. Horizontal composition is given by cartesian product, and vertical composition is given by usual composition of morphisms of schemes.

Then we have a 2-functor $BSpec : BRing^{co} \to BScheme$ where "$co$" means we reverse the 2-cells but not the 1-cells. Your senior mathematician wants to regard this as a 2-functor $BSpec : BRing^{coop} \to BScheme$, where "$op$" means we reverse the 1-cells but not the 2-cells, and "$coop$" means we reverse both 1-cells and 2-cells. See the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/opposite+2-category).

I think Maxime Ramzi's point that the 1-functoriality here corresponds to carrying coproducts to products is a pretty good reason to argue that we really shouldn't be reversing the tensor order.

A complicating factor is that $BRing$ and $BScheme$ as I've defined them above are under-specified -- does $A \otimes B$ mean that we compose $A$ first and then $B$, or the other way around? Does $X \times Y$ mean we compose $X$ first and then $Y$, or the other way around? It seems to me whatever the conventions, they should be chosen the same in both cases. In which case you don't need to reverse the tensor order when applying $Spec$.

Comment: I am not sure why we need these 2-categorical aspects? Given a monoidal category $\mathcal C$, we can always cook up a 2-category $B\,\mathcal C$, but this passage might be lossy in the sense that it only sees monoidal categories modulo "Morita equivalences", I think. What you did seems to be applying this construction to the coCartesian monoidal category $(\operatorname{Ring},\otimes)$ and the Cartesian monoidal category $(\operatorname{Sch},\times)$.

Comment: @Z.M Sure, passing to the 2-category merely puts us in a position where the two independent dualities have names that I can refer to (op and co). But the passage from a monoidal category to a 2-category with one (specified) object is not lossy -- it is an equivalence.

Comment: But you are talking about 2-categories, not *pointed* 2-categories: there is a difference between 2-functors and pointed 2-functors, I think.